# Unable to get access to a Java function from JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

In a Java class (myClass), I have the following method :

`public Location getPointSuivantBase()`.

I want to use it from JNI. When I try to get an id for this function with

`idGetPointSuivantBase=env->GetMethodID(jMyClass,"getPointSuivantBase","()Landroid/location/Location;");`

the app crashes saying that this function doesn't exist.

The same call, used for a `Location` class function (`env->GetMethodID(jLocation,"getLatitude","()D")`) correctly returns an id for the function.

What could cause the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there because the `getPointSuivantBase` was not used anymore in the Java code and, in my debug build type, the "minify enabled" option was set to true.